# How to set fetch size in Hibernate against an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc

When programming directly in JDBC against an Oracle database you can call `stmt.setFetchSize(fetchSize)` on the statement to determine the max number of records to fetch in one round trip from the small default value.  I'd like to do this from withing Hibernate 3.2.

Can someone tell me where this would be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Query.setFetchSize()`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFetchSize(int)).